# How to add Colorpicker in Rails Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to implement this http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about or any other color picker in one of the Active Admin form.

Any help is appreaciated.

Thanks,
GS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to get that working is simply add a class to your input using the `input_html` options.

```
f.input :color, input_html: { class: 'colorpicker' }
```

And then in `active_admin.js.coffee`, add in the code to turn `.colorpicker` input fields into color pickers.

If you are going to be making a lot of them, or adding options to them, it might be worth it to make a [custom Formtastic input](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) that adds those classes and merges the options that can get picked up by the colorpicker library.

Answer (score 9):

Because you want to use a "raw" library, it will be a little more complicated to do, you should rename the paths of the images that library are using, javascripts and so on... so i will recommend you to use another colorpicker with rails-integration, it will be a lot easier, check this one for example [jQuery colorpicker for Rails](https://github.com/kostia/jquery-minicolors-rails), to use this follow this steps

first your gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-minicolors-rails'
```

second add requiere for js to active_admin and load the minicolors() function

```
active_admin.js

//= require active_admin/base
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.minicolors
jQuery( function($) {
    $(".colorpicker").minicolors()
});
```

third add the css to the top of the sass active admin

```
active_admin.css.scss

/*
*= require jquery.minicolors
*/
// SASS variable overrides must be declared before loading up Active Admin's styles.
//
// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
// `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.css.scss` in the
// Active Admin source.
//
// For example, to change the sidebar width:
// $sidebar-width: 242px;

// Active Admin's got SASS!
@import "active_admin/mixins";
@import "active_admin/base";

// Overriding any non-variable SASS must be done after the fact.
// For example, to change the default status-tag color:
//
//   .status_tag { background: #6090DB; }
```

and finally in your form something like this

```
f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'colorpicker' }
```

you can see that i use the class colopicker to identify the input with the jquery function

you can apply more css to this, but this was enough for me and was the easiest way, *regards!*

Comment: nice! small enhancement: use `$("input[type='color']").minicolors()` and then you will not need , `input_html: { class: 'colorpicker' }` snippet (if formtastic will auto-define your field as `:color` type, or you can do it manually http://www.rubydoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/Formtastic/Inputs/ColorInput)

Answer (score 2):

You can use html5 color input. Here is an example:

`f.input :color, as: :color`

I'm using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.1 and it works fine for me.